# Creating string with escape java

Tags: java, string, escaping, concatenation

I have the following problem, I have a string array like that

```
String[] myArray = {"AAAA","BBBB","CCCC"};
```

and my purpose is to create another array like that

```
String myNewArray = {"\uAAAA","\uBBBB","\uCCCC"};
```

The problem is that if I try to create the array using a cycle

```
for (int i=0; i<myArray.length; i++) {
    myNewArray[i] = "\u" + myArray[i];
}
```

I receive an "Invalid unicode error", if I use a cycle like that

```
for (int i=0; i<myArray.length; i++) {
    myNewArray[i] = "\\u" + myArray[i];
}
```

I obtain this array

```
String myNewArray = {"\\uAAAA","\\uBBBB","\\uCCCC"};
```

And if I use this cycle

```
for (int i=0; i<myArray.length; i++) {
    myNewArray[i] = "\\u" + myArray[i];
    myNewArray[i] = myNewArray[i].substring(1);
}
```

I obtain this array

```
String myNewArray = {"uAAAA","uBBBB","uCCCC"};
```

Does anyone know how I can do that?

Thanks

Comment: maybe try concatenating as indvidual characters `myNewArray[i] = '\' + ('u' + myArray[i]);`

Comment: it doesn't accept the '\', and if I use '\\' I have this output:
String myNewArray = {"\\uAAAA","\\uBBBB","\\uCCCC"};

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to parse the strings as hexadecimal integers and then convert to `char`s:

```
String[] myArray = {"AAAA", "BBBB", "CCCC"};
String[] myNewArray = new String[myArray.length];
for (int i=0; i<myArray.length; i++) {
    char c = (char) Integer.parseInt(myArray[i], 16);
    myNewArray[i] = String.valueOf(c);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`\uAAAA` is a literal, not a String with five chars. So we can't create it with concatenation. It *is* one char.

Answer (score 0):

The `\` character needs to be escaped.

Therefore, doing `myNewArray[i] = "\\u" + myArray[i]` is actually what you want to do.

Try to print it to clear the matter up.

Comment: No it isn't. He wants unicode chars in the array, not the hex-type strings with a "\\u" prefix.

Answer (score 0):

I actually can't solve your prob, but i can tell you the following:
Your first approach trys to concat a unicode string "\u" (in your case empty <=> invalid) with an nonunicode string. Your second approach is actually correct.
System.out.println( "\u" + "AAAA" ) should print \uAAAA
As a result one can say that your code is correct, my suggestion is to search for encoding options in your runtime enviroment / IDE.

Answer (score 0):

You can just copy and paste the below program..i tested the code..and it is working fine

public class Main {

```
static String a[];
private static String[] myNewArray;

public static void main(String[] args) {


    String[] myArray = {"AAAA", "BBBB", "CCCC"};
    myNewArray = new String[myArray.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
        myNewArray[i] = "\\u" + myArray[i];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(myNewArray[i]);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score -2):

```
String[] myArray = {"AAAA","BBBB","CCCC"};
String[] myNewArray = {"\uAAAA","\uBBBB","\uCCCC"};
        String we="\\u";
        for (int i=0; i<myArray.length; i++) {
    myNewArray[i] = we + myArray[i];

}
```

Comment: The target array shall include unicode chars (in strings). That's something different

Comment: @DanieleMilani There is no need for me to take your whatever code and paste here.